# Java SWING: How to fix size of components in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am creating a simple Window in `GridLayout` and here is my code:

```
package com.company.app;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class SpamGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Loading Program..");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My awesome Program");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(800, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

        JLabel lblTrainPath = new JLabel("Enter Training Folder Path");
        lblTrainPath.setSize(100,10);
        panel.add(lblTrainPath);

        JTextField txtTrainPath = new JTextField();
        txtTrainPath.setSize(100,10);
        panel.add(txtTrainPath);

        JButton btnTrainPath = new JButton("Select");
        panel.add(btnTrainPath);


        JLabel lblTrainPath3 = new JLabel("Enter Training3 Folder Path");
        panel.add(lblTrainPath3);

        JTextField txtTestPath = new JTextField();
        panel.add(txtTestPath);

        JButton btnTestPath = new JButton("Select");
        panel.add(btnTestPath);


        frame.add(panel);

    }
}
```

It generates screen like this:

[image]

As you can see,it is not respecting size of components, showing quite broad on screens. Also when I run program from INtelliJ IDEA, it does not render components unless I resize screen.

I also want a fixed size window having component with custom size.

Please guide

Comment: *"As you can see,it is not respecting size of components, showing quite broad on screens"* That is a feature of `GridLayout` if the app. does not need that, use a different layout (e.g. `GridBagLayout`) or wrap each component in a `JPanel` with flow layout. *"Also when I run program from INtelliJ IDEA, it does not render components unless I resize screen."* `setVisible(true)` should be done last.

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK I will look at Gridbag and Flow Layout. Speaking of Visibility.. I am doing in 3rd line.. where else should I do?

Comment: *"where else should I do?"* ..should be done **last** (line, after all components are added and `pack()` is called.)

Answer (score 1):

The `Font` class allows you to specify font size.

So, to create a font you should code like this:

```
Font f = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
```

The `fontSize` parameter will determine the size of the `Font` 
So, here enter font size you want ..after that set that font instance variable `f` to your `JLabel` instance variable like this:

```
lblTrainPath.setFont(f);
```

and for  having component with custom size.
you should try `pack()` instead of `frame.setSize(800,200)` 
and use this `pack()` after adding all the components to your frame and for fixed size window use `setResizable(false)`...

Comment: `you should try pack() instead of frame.setSize(800,200) and use this pack() after adding all the components to your frame and for `

Can you clarify it?

Comment: 1) *`new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);`* to avoid using 'magic number, that should be `new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);` 2) Playing with font sizes does not really address the underlying problem that it is the layout that forces all cell sizes to be the same. 3) Calling `pack()` is a good idea, and it should be done ***after*** the call to `setResizable(false)`

Comment: No I don't thnk that its matter , calling pack() before or after setResizable() bcz I used pack() before setResizable() and it's working